# Add slashes before custom sign/char in PHP

Tags: php

I want to add slashes before every special char in my string ($x) so my code looks like:

```
preg_quote($x);
```

BUT I dont want it to add slashes before '*' sign, and here starts the problem.
is there a way in PHP to add a slashes (or any sign) before custom characters ?

Comment: uhm `str_replace`?

Comment: Have you an example of `$x` string ?

Answer (score 0):

### Step1:

In `$x` convert your `*` char to a special key like this : `%__STAR__%` for example. You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function to do it.

### Step2:

Pass your `$x` string in a function like [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [addcslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php) for add slashes before every special char.

### Step3:

Roolback step1: In `$x` convert your special key `%__STAR__%` to `*`. You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function too to do it.